# Why Does Rewrite Fail to Bind?

Tags: formal-verification, lean

In the following, the rewrite fails because it *"did not find instance of the pattern in the target expression"*:

```
example (l1:List Nat)(l2:List Nat)(n:Nat)(r:l1.length >= n)(p:l1.length = l2.length+1) : l2.length >= (n-1) :=
by
  rw [Nat.sub_le_iff_le_add]
```

I'm confused why it doesn't bind given that the goal seems to be a perfect fit.  (**note**: this is a simplified version of something larger, and I'm not interested in how to restate the `example` only in why `rw` fails).

After time wasted searching for a more suitable theorem, I ended up writing my own (which does work):

```
def Nat.succ_ge {m:Nat}{n:Nat} (h:m+1 >= n) : (n-1 <= m) :=
by
  rw [Nat.sub_le_iff_le_add]
  exact h

example (l1:List Nat)(l2:List Nat)(n:Nat)(r:l1.length >= n)(p:l1.length = l2.length+1) : l2.length >= (n-1) :=
by
  apply Nat.succ_ge;
  rw [p] at r
  exact r
```

I find it strange since it just uses the original `sub_le_iff_le_add` theorem!  I just don't understand why I can't apply it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rw` is stumped by the difference between `≥` and `≤`.

This is the reason that in Mathlib we always try writing things in terms of `≤`.

One workaround is:

```
example {l1 l2 : List Nat} (r : l1.length ≥ n) (p : l1.length = l2.length + 1) : l2.length ≥ (n-1) := by
  change _ ≤ _
  rw [Nat.sub_le_iff_le_add]
  sorry -- rest of proof
```